# EF4 + Ninject + ExtensionMethods + Repository

Tags: entity-framework-4, extension-methods, ninject

I have an EF4.Model with `Category` table which will be using the `NestedSet` pattern to store child/parent relation, which I think means that EF4 cannot help with its factory methods in retrieving the children becoz there will be no children or `parentId`, just left and right.

I created an `CategoryModelExtensions` static class, but for the children to be retrieved I will need a variable to refer to the repository.

But how can I inject that variable when constructors are not allowed in static classes?

I didn't want to create the Children() method in the repository for I want to be able to write.

```
Category c = _repo.Get(1);
IList<Category> children = c.Children();
```

Help? If my question is not clear please mention it here and I will update it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass it explicitly:

```
public static IList<Category> Children(this Category category, IMyRepository<Category> categories)
{
     // do stuff
}

IList<Category> children = c.Children(_repo);
```